# use <br> tags only body part on Newsletter Email template in PHP

Tags: php, html, templates, html-email

I have been sending a Newsletter using Email Template, and it's working fine. 
But I have a problem with Body part in my newsletter.
Because I have used strip_tags PHP function for removing `<br>` tags from Template, 
Now I need `<br>` tags only for body parts, so any way I will use `<br>` tags for only body part?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more. The question is not that clear.

Comment: Can you put your some code ?

Comment: show us the code pls and normally it is used <br />

Comment: Is your problem that with all the markup stripped, the email arrives without any newlines? If so, you should have mentioned that. And the solutiojn is that the MIME type of the body is incorrect; change to `text/plain`.

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner Wrong. That's only for XHTML, not HTML.

Comment: thanks, I have explained details, I have sending Newsletter using Email template & template are stored in backend system, but when i received newsletter in my Mail box there is not displaying fine, bcz many <br> tags are automaticaly added there, so i have used strip_tags function and its working fine, but now i have Body part on my Newsletter which are displaying details of when i will sending    there is Body where i will added some text Fox Ex. Hello Sir,[Enter] Test newsletter [Enter], but it will displaying in same line, not apply <br> tags, so i want to use <br> tags only for body part

Comment: you can't display it in html if you strip the tags out. If you want to remove access <br> tags do a str_replace instead, replacing multiple brs

Comment: Yes, I first removed unnecessary <br> tags from Email Template using strip tags and then I have used str_repace function. Now my problem is solved. Thank you John